# Change a div background with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change my background div with some other images.

I want that first, myDiv load the first background image on css style, and then within 2/3 seconds of delay add a fade effect change the background image.

If it's possible, I need to do this with jQuery.

Comment: do you want the background image to be changed automatically or after some event??

Comment: automatically after some seconds!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do fade or any other transitions directly on the background image. You can however add another div with second image as its background and `fadeOut()` the original one.

Comment: Right! Thank You! I put the image in position:absolute and z:index:0, and then i add other <img /> to have a fadeOut() effect!!
thx!

Comment: @JohnFaust If this helped solve your answer, please upvote and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you you want? 
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/

EDIT: A bit more Googling - this sounds like what you are trying to do... 
http://www.magneticwebworks.com/jquery-rotating-page-background/

Edit: another go - THis? http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/9621/solved-is-it-possible-to-add-jquery-cycle-to-background-imagess/p1

Comment: No, this one load only one image with a preloader, i need that the div loads some images on background property with delay and fade effects.

Comment: No sorry, cause i see that on your examples, jquery create some div inside the div content.
I've got some div on my div#background and i can't insert other div..i need to change the background-image of div#background

Comment: Last trick is ok, but i can't add any div inside the content, what i need is change the background-image on containerdiv

Answer (score 0):

this is not fade effect but you can delay and change background image like this.

```
function changebackground(){
    $('#divID').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");  
}


setTimeout(function() { changebackground();}, 3000);
```

Comment: I was able to add a function that makes a fade to the container div, the problem now is that all content has the effect fades

Answer (score 0):

this might be good workaround
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

after you position on top divs with cycle it can be your background - cycle.js give's you lot of options.

if you want only rotate image's in bacground you must first preload that image and second you must put it in other div so that both divs can animate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this, even if you add all the functionality of jQuery UI.

You could append a temporary image, absolutely positioned inside the div for which u want to change background. Let the image fade in, and once it's fully opaque, swap background image for the div. This will be problematic if you have a repeated background, however.

```
var im1 = 'picture1.png';
var im2 = 'picture2.png';
$('#divID').css({'background-image': 'url("'+im1+'")', 'position': 'relative'});
$('#divID').on('click', function() {
    var img = $('<img />', {
        src: im2,
    }).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }).hide();

    $(this).append(img);
    img.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("'+im2+'")');
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Of course, you should move the CSS I included in my script to a .css file, and use a class instead, for more readable code.